# how to automate dropdown for flutter-based website in selenium 4 by using css selectors

Tags: flutter, automation, selenium4, shadow-root

I'm not able to handle drop downs for website developed using flutter. web elements are shadow elements. i have to find shadow root and navigate through source code. and then by css selectors i'm locating a web element, it's too much time consuming, is there any alternative way ?

I tried using css selectors, script executed.
without any error by not selecting drop down, please helpme out